# Open Calender in Fragment on Click of EditText

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-calendar

I am trying to open calender on click of edit text inside the Fragment.But when i am clicking on the the edit text it is throwing null pointer exception to me.
Same code is working fine in the Activity Class but not working fine in the Fargement .

**Exception**

```
03-05 19:02:39.888: E/AndroidRuntime(1092): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-05 19:02:39.888: E/AndroidRuntime(1092): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-05 19:02:39.888: E/AndroidRuntime(1092):     at com.test.newapp.AppTrip.showDialog(AppTrip.java:75)
03-05 19:02:39.888: E/AndroidRuntime(1092):     at com.test.newapp.AppTrip$2.onClick(AppTrip.java:54)
03-05 19:02:39.888: E/AndroidRuntime(1092):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4212)
03-05 19:02:39.888: E/AndroidRuntime(1092):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17476)
03-05 19:02:39.888: E/AndroidRuntime(1092):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:800)
03-05 19:02:39.888: E/AndroidRuntime(1092):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
03-05 19:02:39.888: E/AndroidRuntime(1092):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
03-05 19:02:39.888: E/AndroidRuntime(1092):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371)
03-05 19:02:39.888: E/AndroidRuntime(1092):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-05 19:02:39.888: E/AndroidRuntime(1092):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
03-05 19:02:39.888: E/AndroidRuntime(1092):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
03-05 19:02:39.888: E/AndroidRuntime(1092):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
03-05 19:02:39.888: E/AndroidRuntime(1092):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**Fragment Code**

```
public class AppTrip extends Fragment {
    View rootView;
    EditText from_date, to_date;
    DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener date;
    static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 999;
    Calendar myCalendar;
    int val;
    Context context;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        context = getActivity();
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, container, false);
        from_date = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.from_date);
        to_date = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.to_date);
        from_date.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
        to_date.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
        date = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                    int dayOfMonth) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
                myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
                myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
                updateLabel(val);
            }

        };
        from_date.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
                val = 1;
            }
        });

        to_date.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
                val = 2;
            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }

    protected Dialog showDialog(int dateDialogId) {
        final Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
        switch (dateDialogId) {

        case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
            DatePickerDialog _date = new DatePickerDialog(context, date,
                    myCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                    myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                    myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)) {
                @Override
                public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year,
                        int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                    if (year - now.get(Calendar.YEAR) > 1) {
                        view.updateDate(year - 1,
                                myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                                myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
                    }
                    if (year - now.get(Calendar.YEAR) == 1
                            && monthOfYear > now.get(Calendar.MONTH)) {
                        view.updateDate(year, myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                                myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
                    }
                    if (year - now.get(Calendar.YEAR) == 1
                            && monthOfYear == now.get(Calendar.MONTH)
                            && dayOfMonth > now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)) {
                        view.updateDate(year, myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                                myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
                    }
                    if (year < now.get(Calendar.YEAR))

                        view.updateDate(myCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                                myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                                myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

                    if (monthOfYear < now.get(Calendar.MONTH)
                            && year == now.get(Calendar.YEAR))
                        view.updateDate(myCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                                myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                                myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

                    if (dayOfMonth < now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
                            && year == now.get(Calendar.YEAR)
                            && monthOfYear == now.get(Calendar.MONTH))
                        view.updateDate(myCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                                myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                                myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
                }
            };
            return _date;
        }

        return null;
    }

    private void updateLabel(int val) {
        String myFormat = "dd/MM/yy"; // In which you need put here
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.US);
        Log.d("Date value ", "===" + sdf.format(myCalendar.getTime()));
        if (val == 1)
            from_date.setText(sdf.format(myCalendar.getTime()));
        else
            to_date.setText(sdf.format(myCalendar.getTime()));

    }
}
```

Comment: **showDialog(int)** method is deprecated. Use Dialogfragment.

Comment: still i am getting the same exception

Comment: which line u got NPE?

Comment: this one      myCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), in the case DATE_DIALOG_ID:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything is ok in your code two changes you have to do in your code

First do this in `onCreateView`

```
myCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
```

And  add this

```
_date.show();
```

before

```
return _date;
```

Answer (score 1):

Change from

```
 myCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),
 myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
 myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH))
```

to

```
 now.get(Calendar.YEAR),
 now.get(Calendar.MONTH),
 now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH))
```

in ***showDialog()*** method.

You forgot to initialize ***Calendar myCalendar;*** on onCreateView()

```
 myCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
```

Comment: remove this.  from_date.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
        to_date.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);

Comment: still i calender is not opening

Comment: set this for edittext in xml file  android:focusable="true"
           android:focusableInTouchMode="true"

Comment: also check u have forgotten to call dialog.show() method in DatePickerDialog.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49113/discussion-between-piyush-gupta-and-pooja-dubey)

Answer (score 0):

You are using the instance of myCalendar which isn't initialized. Try using now instead of myCalendar.

Answer (score 0):

Inside fragments showdialog() method doesn't work. You can do that,  setonclicklistener on from_date  and call DatePickerDialog inside it. Do the other things same as you do in your activity class..
Hopefully that help you.